How to change the keyboard keybindings for "up" and "down" in the VS Code CTRL+P and CTRL+SHIFT+P menus
The default keybinding to bring up the menu(s) which looks like this

in Visual Studio Code are

CTRL + P
CTRL + SHIFT + P

Actually, there are two such menus. I show the screenshot only for one of them.
I do not know the name of this menu. It may be called the quick menu, information which I inferr from the keyboard shortcut names.
When interacting with this menu, the default keybindings to move the selected item Up and Down are the UpArrow and DownArrow keys.
How can I change this keybinding such that instead of UpArrow, the shortcut is Shift+UpArrow. Similarly for DownArrow.

The keybinding names are

quickInput.next
quickInput.previous

You can find them in the GUI Keyboard Shortcuts Editor.
If you prefer to edit the Keyboard JSON file directly, here are the relevant lines from keybindings.json.
    {
        "key": "shift+up",
        "command": "quickInput.previous",
        "when": "inQuickInput && quickInputType == 'quickPick'"
    },
    {
        "key": "up",
        "command": "-quickInput.previous",
        "when": "inQuickInput && quickInputType == 'quickPick'"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+down",
        "command": "quickInput.next",
        "when": "inQuickInput && quickInputType == 'quickPick'"
    },
    {
        "key": "down",
        "command": "-quickInput.next",
        "when": "inQuickInput && quickInputType == 'quickPick'"
    }

